# Can I execute test method via Anonymous Window?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to call my Test class's method to see if I can validate the data that is being created as a part of `testSetup`. Here is my code:

```
@isTest
   public class Test_Controller {

    @testSetup static void setUpTestData(){
    Account act = new Account();
    act.Name = 'TestAccount';
    insert act;

    Contact con = new Contact();
    con.AccountId = act.Id;
    con.FirstName = 'FName';
    con.LastName = 'LName';
    insert con;

    List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
    for(Integer i=0; i<3; i++){
        Case cs = new Case();
        cs.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        cs.AccountId = act.Id;
        cs.ContactId = con.Id;
        cs.Subject ='Test Case'+i;
        cs.Status = 'New';
        cs.Origin = 'Phone';
        caseList.add(cs);
    }

    insert caseList;
    System.debug('caseList' +caseList);
  }

  @isTest
  static void testCases(){
    List<Case> testRecords = [Select Subject From Case];
    System.debug('caseList' +testRecords);
  }
}
```

When I run this code via **Anonymous Window**, I am getting this error:

> Line: 1, Column: 31
>   Method is not visible: void Test_Controller.testCases()

Here is how I've tried executing in the Anonymous Window:

```
Test_Controller.testCases();
```

Answer (score 3):

As for the error:

> Line: 1, Column: 31 Method is not visible: void Test_Controller.testCases()

This is because its declared as private (no access modifier specified is private), and thus you cannot call it outside the context of the class.

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm):

> If you do not specify an access modifier, the method or variable is private.

To be able to access the method outside the class, you will need to declare it as `public`, so your method declaration should look as below.

```
@isTest
public static void testCases(){
   ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE ON QUESTION**

> Can I execute test method via Anonymous Window?

**No**. With a quick test I could confirm that even if you declare it as `public`, it is not accessible outside the testing framework. Trying it from anonymous window results in error as below:

> System.TypeException: Cannot call test methods in non-test context

Notice the below excerpt from [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro):

> The visibility of a test method doesn’t matter, so declaring a test method as public or private doesn’t make a difference as the testing framework is always able to access test methods. For this reason, the access modifiers are omitted in the syntax.

The available options to be able to run a test method as mentioned in the [Run Unit Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_unit_tests_running.htm) are as below:

> To run a test, use any of the following:
>
> - The Salesforce user interface
> - The Force.com IDE
> - The Lightning Platform Developer Console
> - The API

Comment: I am sure I have tried that as well. But my actual questions was: **Can I execute test method via Anonymous Window?**

Comment: @AustinEvans I did a quick test and tried using `public` modifier on a test method and called it from anonymous window, and it fails. I have updated the answer to emphasize your original question. Hope it helps.

Comment: It will be nice to know why was this answer downvoted, at least that will help to understand and make any relevant updates.

Comment: Have my upvote to offset it. It seems like there's just too much to the test framework (setup methods, isolation, `startTest()`/`stopTest()` to be workable outside an explicit test run context.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed. That's true. I initially had thought that you could actually call a public method though, unless I was proven wrong with a quick test. But that does seem to make sense as it will lead to all complexities of data visibility, and other aspects as you have mentioned.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for providing more info. And I have just clicked the button: **Run Test** to see the debug logs. I am just trying to broaden my skills and understanding of how we can possibly get to see the logs.